# How does one add a library extracted from a project into a new Xcode project?

Tags: c++, xcode

An open source project refactored their code to make a library separate from the UI. They made the library available as folders extracted from an IDE project. For the Mac download the folders contain dynlibs, c/c++ headers, and other files. Below is link to the library download and also summary of the contents.

The limited help i found through internet search has not enabled me to successfully add this library to an Xcode project and use. Can someone look at what was provided and describe what needs to be done to add the library and associate files to an Xcode project and use? If it is relevant i am using Xcode 14.2.

https://github.com/sfztools/sfizz/releases/tag/1.2.3

```
`\sfizz-1.2.3-macos\usr\local\bin\
sfizz_render

\sfizz-1.2.3-macos\usr\local\include
sfizz.h
sfizz.hpp
sfizz_message.h

\sfizz-1.2.3-macos\usr\local\lib
libsfizz.1.2.3.dylib
libsfizz.1.dylib
libsfizz.dylib

\sfizz-1.2.3-macos\usr\local\lib\pkgconfig
sfizz.pc

\sfizz-1.2.3-macos\usr\local\share\man\man1
sfizz_render.1
```